# Scripted partition creation

Tags: raid, filesystems, fdisk, partition

I need to routinely do these steps on various machines that have the same hardware:

1. delete any partitions on /dev/sda
2. create a 100G primary partition on /dev/sda
3. change partition type of created partition to linux raid auto (type fd)
4. write the table
5. do the exact same thing for /dev/sdb

I currently use fdisk -u for doing this, but i was thinking, there has to be a way of scripting this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1

cat <<EOF | fdisk /dev/sda
n
p
1
+102400M

t
fd
w
EOF

partprobe
```

Answer (score 4):

The [parted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) command has a scripting interface as does the [sfdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk) command, either of these could be used to do what you want.